# OpenLayers 4 - maximum number of layers

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, openlayers

What is the maximum number of overlays / layers that I can simultaneously load onto an online OpenLayers 4 / OSM map?

Comment: How many have you tried to add?

Comment: havent benchmarked.  suggestions?

Comment: How big are the layers, are they vector or raster. If raster are they provided by tile services. What sort of internet connection do you have

Comment: also see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85142/maximum-number-of-layers-in-openlayers2-with-geoext